# XSL:for-each - Trouble with duplicate nodes in XML, needs to be output to separate lines in a CSV file

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0

Apologies if this has been answered elsewhere, but I have been unable to find a solution. I'm preparing a data set for Microsoft School Data Sync, where I generate a number of CSV files based on a XML file. In the file I have a number of carers with one or several carerrelationship (children). In the output CSV I need each child to be on a separate line, each with the contact info (email) of their carer. However, I just can't get the xsl:for-each to work right. Any help or feedback will be much appreciated!

XML -> This is a carer with two children:

```
<person recstatus="1">
    <sourcedid>
      <id>e763fb61-2086-40af-9eb6-d5355d5922bc</id>
    </sourcedid>
    <name>
      <fn>Smith,John</fn>
      <n>
        <family>Smith</family>
        <given>John</given>
      </n>
    </name>
    <email>john.smith@email.com</email>
    <institutionrole institutionroletype="Carer" primaryrole="Yes" />
    <extension>
      <carerrelationship recstatus="1">
        <sourcedid>
          <id>04ba28e9-0934-41c9-aa42-31c0b66f36ad</id>
        </sourcedid>
        <sourcedid>
          <id>300c42ca-c78a-4ec9-9d81-9acb2382bbca</id>
        </sourcedid>
      </carerrelationship>
    </extension>
</person>
```

Here's my XSL

```
 <xsl:result-document href="Guardianrelationship.csv" method="text">
            <xsl:text>SIS ID,Email,Role</xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="$break"/>
            <xsl:for-each select="person[institutionrole/@institutionroletype = 'Carer']/extension/carerrelationship">
                <xsl:variable name="person" select="."/>
                <xsl:value-of select="sourcedid/id"/><xsl:value-of select="$delimiter"/>
                <xsl:value-of select="ancestor::person/email"/><xsl:value-of select="$delimiter"/>
                <xsl:text>Guardian</xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="$break"/>    
            </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:result-document>
```

Expected result:

```
SIS ID,Email,Role
04ba28e9-0934-41c9-aa42-31c0b66f36ad,john.smith@email.com.no,Guardian
300c42ca-c78a-4ec9-9d81-9acb2382bbca,john.smith@email.no,Guardian
```

Actual result:

```
SIS ID,Email,Role
04ba28e9-0934-41c9-aa42-31c0b66f36ad 300c42ca-c78a-4ec9-9d81-9acb2382bbca,rw347@kirken.no,Guardian
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're currently outputting one line for each carerrelationship, you need to output one line for each sourcedid.

For example

```
<xsl:for-each select="person[institutionrole/@institutionroletype = 'Carer']/extension/carerrelationship/sourcedid">
     <xsl:value-of select="id"/><xsl:value-of select="$delimiter"/>
     <xsl:value-of select="ancestor::person/email"/><xsl:value-of select="$delimiter"/>
     <xsl:text>Guardian</xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="$break"/>    
</xsl:for-each>
```

You can simplify it to

```
<xsl:for-each select="person[institutionrole/@institutionroletype = 'Carer']/extension/carerrelationship/sourcedid">
     <xsl:value-of select="id || $delimiter || ancestor::person/email || $delimiter || 'Guardian' || $break"/>    
</xsl:for-each>
```

or use concat(x,y,z) in place of `||` if using 2.0 rather than 3.0.

Comment: That did it! Thank you!